# DB2 - Determine a future date based on two fields

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I need to calculate a date in DB2 for UNIX.

I have a date field:
    CONTRACT_DT (Examples: 
    2/7/2006,
    8/25/2006,
    11/16/2007,
    2/25/2008,
    12/29/2005)

And a type field
    PRIME (Examples: C, I, E, Z, V, K)

I need to calculate the next date the loan will be reviewed (REVIEW_DT).

- If Prime = Z then every year from CONTRACT_DT
- If Prime = V then every three years from CONTRACT_DT
- If Prime = K then every five years from CONTRACT_DT
- If Prime = NULL or any other letter, then NULL

An example is loan 01 has a CONTRACT_DT of 3/1/2004, and has a PRIME of V.
So I need to count by/add three years to 3/1/2004, until I get a date greater than MTHLY_CLOSE_DT.  (Options would be 2007, 2010, 2013, 2016, 2019,2022).
So correct answer is 3/1/2016.

I realize the structure is a CASE statement, but I have no idea how to pick a date based on year multiples and find the one greater than MNTHLY_CLOSE_DT.

Here's what I have so far:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE "FINANCE"."AL_LOOP_TEST"(OUT r_rvdt DATE)
BEGIN ATOMIC

  DECLARE v_tmgi DATE;
  DECLARE v_ctdt DATE;
  DECLARE v_rvdt DATE;    
SET v_tmgi = '2014-09-01';  --Close month
SET v_ctdt = '2012-06-02';  -- CONTRACT_DT
SET v_rvdt = v_ctdt;  -- Starting Value for v_rvdt

WHILE (v_rvdt < v_tmgi)  -- While Review Dt is less than Close Month
  DO
  SET v_rvdt = (v_rvdt  + 5 YEAR); -- Add 5 years to date
END WHILE;

  SET r_rvdt = v_rvdt;
END
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have some sql code you've tried so far?  From my initial look at this, you may have to implement a [looping construct](http://www.ibmpressbooks.com/articles/article.asp?p=31963&seqNum=4) for this

Comment: No, I was constructing it in my head, and realized I had no idea how to go through (Loop as you point out) all the possibilities of dates, and find the first one after MNTHLY_CLOSE_DT.

Comment: Well as you get closer, post the code and I'll be happy to help to the best of my ability as I'm from the TSQL world more than DB2's flavor.  It'll help get a better answer (on this specific site) if we have code to help you out with.  Check this out, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I added starting code.  I don't have a return value, to see if it's working.

Comment: looking at the code(and briefly looking over some DB2 sql), you should be getting back the value of r_rvdt as-is, what is it returning though?

Comment: Need to retract that.  I recompiled and I'm returning the date now.

Comment: Nice!  If your procedure is now the best answer, post it so we can upvote and you can mark as best answer.  Seems odd but helps the next person and it seems DB2 has a lot less answers than Sql Server.

Answer (score 0):

Jimmy, Thanks for your help.  This is what I created:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE "X"."AL_LOOP_TEST" ( OUT "R_RVDT" DATE )
  LANGUAGE SQL
  NOT DETERMINISTIC
  EXTERNAL ACTION
  MODIFIES SQL DATA
  OLD SAVEPOINT LEVEL
BEGIN ATOMIC

 DECLARE v_tmgi DATE;
 DECLARE v_ctdt DATE;
 DECLARE v_rvdt DATE;    
SET v_tmgi = '2014-09-01';  --Close month
SET v_ctdt = '2002-06-02';  -- CONTRACT_DT
SET v_rvdt = v_ctdt;  -- Starting Value for v_rvdt

WHILE (v_rvdt < v_tmgi)  -- While Review Dt is less than Close Month
  DO
  SET v_rvdt = (v_rvdt  + 5 YEAR); -- Add 5 years to date
END WHILE;

  SET r_rvdt = v_rvdt;
END;
```